# Count the attr size = "small" using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want length of the size attribute contains "small"

```
<div class="handle" id="parentSmall-1" value="0" size="small">
    <div class="csd a" id="child1"></div>
    <div class="csd a" id="child2"></div>
</div>
<div class="handle" id="parentSmall-2" value="1" size="small">
    <div class="csd b" id="child3"></div>
    <div class="csd b" id="child4"></div>
</div>
<div class="handle" id="parentLarge-1" value="2" size="large">
    <div class="csd c" id="child5"></div>
    <div class="csd c" id="child6"></div>
</div>
<div class="handle" id="parentLarge-2" value="3" size="large">
    <div class="csd d" id="child7"></div>
    <div class="csd d" id="child8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your attempt? `I want length of the size attribute contains "small"` What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$('[size="small"]').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` to get the total number of element with class `handle` whose have `size` attribute value equal to `small`:

```
$('.handle[size="small"]').length
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/auaeX/)**